# What does "virtual" mouse mean in jQuery Mobile?

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

What does "virtual" mouse mean in jQuery Mobile? I understand that it's related with touching the display, but nothing more.

As far as I tried, `click` event reacts on touch, not only on `click` by physical mouse. Same about `mouseup`/`vmouseup` and `mousedown`/`vmousedown`. So, I don't understand v-events uniqueness.

Comment: I think is a plugin for making the better performance depending on the device.
https://api.jquerymobile.com/vmousedown/

Comment: "the plugin will take care of registering the correct listeners behind the scenes" - here is the full description: http://api.jquerymobile.com/vclick/